# ORA-00905: missing keyword is coming for this code

Tags: sql, case

```
select employee_id,case first_name when first_name = "Steve" then "My name is Steve" 
                        else first_name
end
from hr.employees
where 
employee_id = 150;
```

Please rectify this error for me

Comment: Are you sure you are using that case statement correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a type. Instead of `case first_name when first_name = "Steve"` you need to use `case when first_name = 'Steve'` or `case first_name when 'Steve'`

```
select employee_id,case when first_name = 'Steve' then 'My name is Steve' 
                        else first_name
end as First_Name
from hr.employees
where 
employee_id = 150;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select employee_id,
   case first_name when 'Steve' then 'My name is Steve' else first_name end 
from hr.employees where employee_id = 150;
```

also single quotes for strings.  Also reading the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/CASE-statement.html#GUID-F4251A23-0284-4990-A156-00A92F83BC35) is helpful